# Query an object via multiple pivot tables with Laravel's ORM Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

What I want to do, is to retrieve data through multiple relationships (pivot tables). 
I have three database tables

`users`, `cities`, and `jobs`.

They are built like this (They aren't, just to give you a glimpse)

**Users table**
`id int(11) PK, Autoincrement`,
`name varchar(255)`

**Cities table**
`id int(11) PK, Autoincrement`,
`name varchar(255)`

**Jobs table**
`id int(11) PK, Autoincrement`,
`name varchar(255)`

---

Now I have pivot tables, because these are many to many relationships. I got the tables `city_user` and `job_user`.

**CityUser table**
`city_id int(11)`,
`user_id int(11)`

**JobUser table**
`job_id int(11)`,
`user_id int(11)`

In every Class (`User`, `City`, `Job`), I got the relationships defined with a `belongsToMany` method.

**City class**

```
/**
 * Defines the relation between the city and its users
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'city_user');
}
```

**User class**

```
/**
 * Defines the relation between the user and its cities
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(City::class, 'city_user');
}
```

The same goes for the jobs table. What I now want to do is to get all users that are in a specific city and have a specific job.

Let's imagine I want to query all users who live in City with the ID 5, and have the job with the ID 10.

Going for one relationshiop is fairly easy

`$users = City::find(5)->users;`

or

`$users = Job::find(10)->users;`.

But, how do I achieve that for multiple relationships in this case? I tried to do it like this

```
$users = City::find(10)->with(['users' => function($query) use ($jobId) {
    // Here I'm stuck. I wouldn't know how to query further? Maybe like this
    return $query->with('jobs')->whereJobId($jobId);
}]);
```

But, when I do it like this, I'm getting 0 results, so there must be something wrong. Any ideas?

I'm getting an error though

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'job_id' in 'where clause'' in

I also tried it like this (inside the `with(['consultants'])`)

```
$query->with(['jobs' => function ($query) use ($jobId) {
    $query->whereJobId($jobId);
}]);
```

but that doesn't look right. Also I'm getting a `Collection` of `Cities`, but I need one of `Users`.

Then I tired it (temporary) like this

```
$users = User::with(['cities' => function ($query) use($cityId) {
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany $query */
    $query->wherePivot('city_id', $cityId);
}])->get();
```

But, then I'm getting ALL users, instead of just the ones, which is even more confusing, because the documentation says

---

> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify additional query constraints for the eager loading query. Here's an example:

```
$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}])->get();
```

> In this example, Eloquent will only eager load posts that if the post's title column contains the word first. Of course, you may call other query builder to further customize the eager loading operation:

But why doesn't it work then?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your fatal error this way:

```
$users = City::find(10)->with(['users.jobs', function($query) use ($jobId) {
        $query->whereJobId($jobId);
    });
}]);
```

But this will not filter the users for a specific job ID. For example we have two users with IDs `1` and `#2`. User `1` is related to job `10` while user `2` is not. The code above will give you both users for `$jobId = 10`, because the users query will be executed first without any filters for jobs and the jobs query will be executed after the users query.

You have to use the `join()` method of the query builder:

```
$users = User::join('job_user', 'users.id', '=', 'job_user.user_id')
    ->join('city_user', 'users.id', '=', 'city_user.user_id')
    ->where('job_user.job_id', $jobId)
    ->where('city_user.city_id', $cityId)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I already solved the fatal error, and then did something else, which did what you said. I'm now getting all users, even though I'm filtering. Thanks for that!

Isn't there any other way except using the `join()` method? Because I thought that's exactly what the relationships and `with` method is for. If I have to write all joins manually, I could also write plain SQL, and be faster with it. Thanks though, I upvoted you

Comment: I know using `join()` is a bit dirty in an Eloquent sense, but I don't think there is another solution. That's because Eloquent fires one query per relation.
For example `User::with('jobs')->get()` will fire these two queries:
#1: `SELECT * FROM users`
#2: `SELECT * FROM jobs JOIN job_user ON users.id = job_user.user_id`

I don't think there is an Eloquent method that joins the `job_user` pivot table and adds a `WHERE` constraint for the first query, so we have to do it manually. :/

Comment: That sucks pretty bad. I think I would do the query in Plain SQL then, since it would be faster, and I got it finished already. Let's see if someone has an idea

Comment: Since no one answered anymore, I tried your approach. However, since I have a field `name` in a foreign table and in the `users` table the name from the foreign table overrides the one from the users table. I know, I could simply define in `get()` which fields I want, but doesn't it work somehow automatic?

Comment: I don't think so. The best way to deal with it is probably `get(['users.*'])` to select only the users table columns.